# Query Optimization Tips

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization

I been looking for some general Tips and Tricks for Query Opitimization in SQL Server 2008.

I came accross the below which am quite unsure what are the consequences of using views / triggies

- Try to replace views with original source table
- Triggers should not be used if possible, incorporate the logic of trigger in stored
  procedure

Can someone shed light on these explaining pros and cons and also point me to list of general Tips and Tricks for Query optimization.

Comment: Is my question not sensible? or the guy who down voted is so genius that he doesnt understand what am asking? Atleast make a comment when down voting; so that other guys can understand whats are you upto or is there anything wrong in the question

Comment: Perhaps they felt that your question was inappropriate based on the [StackOverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).  It is not a specific question, but an invitation to an open ended discussion.  In any event, I didn't cast a vote either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view is a virtual table formed from a query such as 'SELECT a, b FROM tableC'  This creates a 'virtual table' of a & b.  A source table is the table its self, and it is far more efficient to be able to 'SELECT * FROM tableC' so that a virtual table is not created.

Triggers are events that are triggered when a specified event happens, such as a specific query.  Stored procedures are compiled transactions and can function exactly like a trigger except they are far more efficient.  In short, do not use triggers.

I would seriously consider this [http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Tuning-Dan-Tow/dp/0596005733/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1345679033&sr=8-1&keywords=sql+optimization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005733)

Comment: For the virtual tables answer.  The database design should be such that queries generally need all of the information returned from the given source columns on each row returned.  So if you have a query where you are selecting only certain columns from a table, your schema is not efficient.

Comment: I disagree that a view is a "virtual table." But @David I'm not sure I follow your logic. So if I have an OrderDetails table and I use a query to get the total number of units of product x that will be needed for orders that have not yet shipped, my schema is rubbish because my query is not looking at the unit price column, which is irrelevant to the query I'm currently running?

Comment: You would use a query such as 'SELECT COUNT(unit) FROM OrderDetails', and since count is not returning a "list of rows" using only the 'unit' column, no virtual table is created, so no, your schema is not rubbish in that case.  If you are running 'SELECT unit FROM OrderDetails' and then counting using some other function then you are creating a virtual table, and it is not efficient.